# Efficient way to generate a seemingly random permutation from a very large set without repeating?

Tags: algorithm, random, permutation

I have a very large set (**billions** or more, it's expected to grow exponentially to some level), and I want to generate seemingly random elements from it without repeating. I know I can pick a random number and repeat and record the elements I have generated, but that takes more and more memory as numbers are generated, and wouldn't be practical after couple millions elements out.

I mean, I could say 1, 2, 3 up to billions and **each would be constant time without remembering all the previous**, or I can say 1,3,5,7,9 and on then 2,4,6,8,10, but is there a more sophisticated way to do that and eventually get a seemingly random permutation of that set?

**Update**

1, The set does not change size in the generation process. I meant when the user's input increases linearly, the size of the set increases exponentially.

2, In short, the set is like the set of every integer from 1 to 10 billions or more.

3, In long, it goes up to 10 billion because each element carries the information of many independent choices, for example. Imagine an RPG character that have 10 attributes, each can go from 1 to 100 (for my problem different choices can have different ranges), thus there's 10^20 possible characters, number "10873456879326587345" would correspond to a character that have "11, 88, 35...", and I would like an algorithm to generate them one by one without repeating, but makes it **looks** random.

Comment: Is the size of the set fixed throughout the process, or will it grow between picking two numbers?

Comment: Is it a set or a list/array of items you have? I.e. is it indexable?. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_type

Comment: @biziclop The size of the set is fixed throughout the process. Thanks for asking, updating my question now.

Comment: @Paddy3118 It's a enumerable set. Think of it something like a set of every integer from 1 to 10 billion or more.

Comment: if two characters can share at least some of the attribute settings, why not just generate each attribute randomly?

Comment: @גלעדברקן why would that make a difference?

Comment: You can do this with a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/), and the only state you should have to save is a single number. You start with 1 and transform it. The next time, transform 2, etc. You vary the sequence by either starting at a different number, or by selecting a different coprime number for the computation.

Comment: @JimMischel This looks very interesting! I'll have a look and reply again soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the interesting question.  You can create a "pseudorandom"* (cyclic) permutation with a few bytes using modular exponentiation.  Say we have n elements.  Search for a prime p that's bigger than n+1.  Then find a primitive root g modulo p.  Basically by definition of primitive root, the action x --> (g * x) % p is a cyclic permutation of {1, ..., p-1}.  And so x --> ((g * (x+1))%p) - 1 is a cyclic permutation of {0, ..., p-2}.  We can get a cyclic permutation of {0, ..., n-1} by repeating the previous permutation if it gives a value bigger (or equal) n.

I implemented this idea as a Go package. https://github.com/bwesterb/powercycle

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/bwesterb/powercycle"
)

func main() {
    var x uint64
    cycle := powercycle.New(10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(x)
        x = cycle.Apply(x)
    }
}
```

This outputs something like

```
0
6
4
1
2
9
3
5
8
7
```

but that might vary off course depending on the generator chosen.

It's fast, but not super-fast: on my five year old i7 it takes less than 210ns to compute one application of a cycle on 1000000000000000 elements.  More details:

```
BenchmarkNew10-8                     1000000          1328 ns/op
BenchmarkNew1000-8                    500000          2566 ns/op
BenchmarkNew1000000-8                  50000         25893 ns/op
BenchmarkNew1000000000-8              200000          7589 ns/op
BenchmarkNew1000000000000-8             2000        648785 ns/op
BenchmarkApply10-8                  10000000           170 ns/op
BenchmarkApply1000-8                10000000           173 ns/op
BenchmarkApply1000000-8             10000000           172 ns/op
BenchmarkApply1000000000-8          10000000           169 ns/op
BenchmarkApply1000000000000-8       10000000           201 ns/op
BenchmarkApply1000000000000000-8    10000000           204 ns/op
```

Why did I say "pseudorandom"?  Well, we are always creating a very specific kind of cycle: namely one that uses modular exponentiation.  It looks pretty pseudorandom though.

Comment: i did something else at the time... but good to know there is a solution! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would use a random number and swap it with an element at the beginning of the set.

Here's some pseudo code

```
set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
picked = 0
Function PickNext(set, picked)
  If picked > Len(set) - 1 Then
    Return Nothing
  End If
  // random number between picked (inclusive) and length (exclusive)
  r = RandomInt(picked, Len(set))
  // swap the picked element to the beginning of the set
  result = set[r]
  set[r] = set[picked]
  set[picked] = result
  // update picked
  picked++
  // return your next random element
  Return temp
End Function
```

Every time you pick an element there is one swap and the only extra memory being used is the *picked* variable. The swap can happen if the elements are in a database or in memory.

**EDIT** Here's a jsfiddle of a working implementation http://jsfiddle.net/sun8rw4d/

JavaScript

```
var set = [];
set.picked = 0;
function pickNext(set) {
    if(set.picked > set.length - 1) { return null; }
    var r = set.picked + Math.floor(Math.random() * (set.length - set.picked));
    var result = set[r];
    set[r] = set[set.picked];
    set[set.picked] = result;
    set.picked++;
    return result;
}

// testing
for(var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    set.push(i);
}
while(pickNext(set) !== null) { }
document.body.innerHTML += set.toString();
```

**EDIT 2** Finally, a random binary walk of the set. This can be accomplished with O(Log2(N)) stack space (memory) which for 10billion is only 33. There's no shuffling or swapping involved. Using trinary instead of binary might yield even better pseudo random results.

```
// on the fly set generator
var count = 0;
var maxValue = 64;
function nextElement() {
    // restart the generation
    if(count == maxValue) {
        count = 0;
    }
    return count++;
}

// code to pseudo randomly select elements
var current = 0;
var stack = [0, maxValue - 1];
function randomBinaryWalk() {
    if(stack.length == 0) { return null; }
    var high = stack.pop();
    var low = stack.pop();
    var mid = ((high + low) / 2) | 0;
    // pseudo randomly choose the next path
    if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
        if(low <= mid - 1) {
            stack.push(low);
            stack.push(mid - 1);
        }
        if(mid + 1 <= high) {
            stack.push(mid + 1);
            stack.push(high);
        }
    } else {
        if(mid + 1 <= high) {
            stack.push(mid + 1);
            stack.push(high);
        }
        if(low <= mid - 1) {
            stack.push(low);
            stack.push(mid - 1);
        }
    }
    // how many elements to skip
    var toMid = (current < mid ? mid - current : (maxValue - current) + mid);
    // skip elements
    for(var i = 0; i < toMid - 1; i++) {
        nextElement();
    }
    current = mid;
    // get result
    return nextElement();
}

// test
var result;
var list = [];
do {
    result = randomBinaryWalk();
    list.push(result);
} while(result !== null);
document.body.innerHTML += '<br/>' + list.toString();
```

Here's the results from a couple of runs with a small set of 64 elements. JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yooLjtgu/

> > 30,46,38,34,36,35,37,32,33,31,42,40,41,39,44,45,43,54,50,52,53,51,48,47,49,58,60,59,61,62,56,57,55,14,22,18,20,19,21,16,15,17,26,28,29,27,24,25,23,6,2,4,5,3,0,1,63,10,8,7,9,12,11,13
> >
> > 30,14,22,18,16,15,17,20,19,21,26,28,29,27,24,23,25,6,10,8,7,9,12,13,11,2,0,63,1,4,5,3,46,38,42,44,45,43,40,41,39,34,36,35,37,32,31,33,54,58,56,55,57,60,59,61,62,50,48,49,47,52,51,53

As I mentioned in my comment, unless you have an efficient way to *skip* to a specific point in your "on the fly" generation of the set this will not be very efficient.

Comment: This is basically the Fisher-Yates shuffle done step by step.

Comment: @biziclop - An in-place version anyways, more like Sattolo's algorithm from the same wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Pencil-and-paper_method  The one improvement I made was moving the picked elements to the beginning which allows the set to grow while picking is still going on.

Comment: Sets don't have beginning or end and there is no meaning to the i'th element of a set so the subscripting above doesn't apply to sets.

Comment: I can't make any "movements" because the set have billions of elements and does not fit entirely into memory -- Your first line would simply not work. Sorry! The elements are actually generated on the fly, by their index. Again, I'm looking for something like the examples I gave that does not requiring remembering what has been generated or what's left.

Comment: @Paddy3118 - I don't know where you got that definition of a set, but to most, In mathematics, a set is a collection of distinct objects. Collections have a size and can be enumerated.

Comment: @Zuoanqh - If the elements are generated on the fly and you can't afford the cost of remembering already selected elements, your only chance is a counter that rolls over when you get to the max size and starts again, but this will have a lot of wasted calculation as many elements will be generated and thrown away because it's not their ~pseudo~ random time to appear.

Comment: @Zuoanqh - I've add a randomized binary walk that should be more what you are looking for.

Comment: @LouisRicci - From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type) "In computer science, a set is an abstract data type that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values." What I mean is that subscripting is not an operation for a set. "The i'th element" of a set has no meaning. Enumerating a set? If you could expand on what you mean by that then we might aid clarity.

Comment: @Paddy3118 - If you can lookup Set ADT you could also look up enumerating. The elements in a set are unordered, but when you display them you display them in a specific order. This order is implementation specific, but it's repeatable. When you are displaying the values within a Set ADT, you are *enumerating* through those values, giving them an order (even if the order is arbitrarily decided by the implementation). So, when I subscript it is only to represent that arbitrary order when the set is finally enumerated. As far as pedantic definitions or being technically correct, I choose code.

Comment: Does it still work if you do "var maxValue = 10000000000;" ? 'cause that's pretty much what i said in the question. Look at Paddy's solution, there's also a link in the comment that already does what I want, but for a fixed maxValue of 2^31

Comment: @Zuoanqh - Of course it will work for any size, if you only need the index values then you can remove the //how many elements to skip and //skip elements portions of the code and that will simply return the randomized binary walk indices.

Comment: @Zuoanqh - Using a PRNG will leave you choosing a period of 2^34 ~= 17billion which means you'd have to throw away 7billion of the calls to generate your 10billion number sequence. There are many ways you can solve this problem, like choosing a large prime number and doing a modulus *for(var i=1, p=getBigPrime(); i <= 10billion; i++) { console.log( (i * p) % 10billion); }*

Comment: @LouisRicci The question was rhetorical! Of course you can't keep a set that large in memory lol

Answer (score 1):

if it is enumerable then use a pseudo-random integer generator adjusted to the period 0 .. 2^n - 1 where the upper bound is just greater than the size of your set and generate pseudo-random integers discarding those more than the size of your set. Use those integers to index items from your set.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct direction to go. Thanks. the next step for me would be trying to find something with an adjustable period I guess.... But does these generators guarantee every number is generated exactly once before it repeats?

Comment: Some algorithms generate with a period of 2^n - 1. Research Linear feedback shift registers or PCG at http://www.pcg-random.org/

Comment: yes, I've found this after some digging: https://github.com/preshing/RandomSequence/blob/master/randomsequence.h

Comment: That was good enough if i could just figure out how it work and change the period

Comment: I had a look at your link, it doesn't really say every number appears once, or customizable period.

Comment: @Zuoanqh - the table on the PCG landing page gives the period of various algorithms. If you have between 2^31 and 2^32 values in your set then many of the algorithms mentioned show a period of 2^32 - you would have to discard up to half the pseudo-random numbers but those algorithms could be used. Oh, and the period equates to roughly how many different numbers are produced before it will cycle around and produce that same number again.

Answer (score 0):

Pre- compute yourself a series of indices (e.g. in a file), which has the properties you need and then randomly choose a start index for your enumeration and use the series in a round-robin manner.

The length of your pre-computed series should be > the maximum size of the set.

If you combine this (depending on your programming language etc.) with file mappings, your final `nextIndex(INOUT state)` function is (nearly) as simple as `return mappedIndices[state++ % PERIOD];`, if you have a fixed size of each entry (e.g. 8 bytes -> uint64_t).

Of course, the returned value could be > your current set size. Simply draw indices until you get one which is <= your sets current size.

**Update** (In response to question-update):

There is another option to achieve your goal if it is about creating 10Billion unique characters in your RPG: Generate a GUID and write yourself a function which computes your number from the GUID. `man uuid` if you are are on a unix system. Else google it. Some parts of the uuid are not random but contain meta-info, some parts are either systematic (such as your network cards MAC address) or random, depending on generator algorithm. But they are very very most likely unique. So, whenever you need a new unique number, generate a uuid and transform it to your number by means of some algorithm which basically maps the uuid bytes to your number in a non-trivial way (e.g. use hash functions).

Comment: If you mean "generate a permutation of billions of elements as a cache stored in files, then use it", that would take gigabytes of dick space. The space required would also grow at an exponential rate with respect to "amount of attributes" (see metaphor), as suggested in the question. It's a useful strategy in general, but don't work well for this problem, sadly.

Comment: @Zuoanqh I assumed that if you have disk space for your (potentially much larger billions of set-entries), you have large enough disks, too, yet not enough memory to do something "faster". Reading the update now, I start to wonder if your angle of view on the problem is optimal: If the numbers you seek is composed of basically N random numbers in [0..100], what are the odds that 2 players end with the exact same character? You need no bookkeeping at all, imho.

Comment: yea, but that's just an example. in reality there will be millions and millions of "players", and I want something that always works perfectly, instead of something that gets slower and slower over time. it's all about scalability! I could also want this million character today, another couple million tomorrow, and on and on, when I'm done with them i'll just delete it, but i don't want anything the same show up tomorrow.